# StringBuffer is obsolete?

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder, stringbuffer

In the book "Effective Java", Josh Bloch says that

> StringBuffer is largely obsolete and should be replaced by the
>   non-synchronized implementation 'StringBuilder'

.

But in my experience, I've still seen widespread use of the StringBuffer class. Why is the StringBuffer class now obsolete and why should StringBuilder be preferred over StringBuffer except for the increased performance due to non-synchronization?

Comment: You see StringBuffer so widely use because of the same reason you still see the Vector class so widely used, i.e. 1. people read pre-Java 1.5 books. 2. you still find lots of examples on the Net which use StringBuffer. 3. there are still people out there who program/teach Java but are not aware of StringBuilder.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

It's obsolete in that new code *on Java 1.5* should generally use `StringBuilder` - it's *very* rare that you really need to build strings in a thread-safe manner, so why pay the synchronization cost?

I suspect code that you see using `StringBuffer` mostly falls into buckets of:

- Written before Java 1.5
- Written to maintain compatibility with older JDKs
- Written by people who don't know about `StringBuilder`
- Autogenerated by tools which don't know about `StringBuilder`

Comment: I went through the code of StringBuffer and StringBuilder. They're the exactly same except that all methods of StringBuffer are appended with the synchronized keyword.

Comment: @Varun: That wouldn't surprise me at all.

Comment: I suspect that a lot of people who do know about StringBuilder keep using StringBuffer out of sheer habit. I know I have to fight it...

Answer (score 19):

Not everyone reads as widely as you :-)

I'm only half-joking. People copy code and patterns all the time. Many people don't stay in touch with API changes.

Why is StringBuffer obsolete? Because in the vast majority of cases, its synchronised behaviour isn't required. I can't think of a time I've ever needed it. Despite the fact that synchronisation is not now the performance issue it once was, it makes little sense to pay that tax in scenarios where it's unnecessary.

Answer (score 10):

> Why is the StringBuffer class now obsolete?

Because its operations are synchronized, which adds overhead and is rarely useful.

The reason why you still see `StringBuffer` used widely is simply inertia: There are still countless code examples tutorials out there that were never updated to use `StringBuilder`, and people still learn outdated practices (not just this one) from such sources. And even people who know better often fall back to old habits.

Answer (score 5):

I think obsolete is an overstatement.

StringBuffer is synchronized.  StringBuilder is not.

In many (maybe most) cases, you won't care about the thread safety of something used to build strings. You should use StringBuilder in these cases.  In *some* cases, however, you may very well want to make sure actions on the object is thread safe.  StringBuffer is still useful in those cases.

Comment: Not sure I can think of a good reason to have multiple threads building one string, if you cared about the order of the data in the resultant string.

Comment: @Hardwareguy: Some kind of logger I suppose, since you could work by appending a whole message. Would be messy though, and have poor Code Smell.

Answer (score 4):

Not only is synchronisation not required in most cases, it actually gives readers of your code wrong information if you nevertheless use it: namely, the reader could be led to believe that synchronisation is required where it actually isn’t.

Using a `StringBuilder` instead advertises the fact that you don’t expect cross-thread access.

In fact, sending data across threads should almost always be done through well-defined channels of communication anyway, not simply by accessing a synchronised string buffer. So in a way I would recommend *always* using a different solution, even when a `StringBuffer` seems appropriate at first glance.