# For loop is slow

Tags: java, performance, for-loop, arraylist, hashmap

Please have a look at the following code

```
private StringBuffer populateStringWithUnmatchingWords(ArrayList<String>unmatchingWordsHolder)
    {
        StringBuffer unMatchingWordsStr = new StringBuffer("");

        for(int u=0;u<unmatchingWordsHolder.size();u++)
        {
             Iterator iterInWordMap = wordMap.entrySet().iterator();

             while(iterInWordMap.hasNext())
             {
                 Map.Entry mEntry = (Map.Entry)iterInWordMap.next();

                 if(mEntry.getValue().equals(unmatchingWordsHolder.get(u)))
                 {
                       //out.println(matchingWords.get(m)+" : "+true);
                       unMatchingWordsStr.append(mEntry.getKey());
                       unMatchingWordsStr.append(",");
                 }
              }
        }

        return unMatchingWordsStr;
    }
```

This `for loop` takes 8387ms to complete. The `unmatchingWordsHolder` is pretty big too. `wordMap` is a `HashMap` and contains somewhat around 5000 elements as well.

This loop will search whether elements in `unmatchingWordsHolder` are available in `wordMap`. If they are available, then they will be loaded into `unMatchingWordsStr`.

Is there any way for me to speed up this task?

Comment: Can you provide the code used to time this method running, so that we can confirm any proposed solutions are an improvement or not.

Comment: You should provide sample input or code to generate input to make it easier for someone to test.

Comment: you should store `unmatchingWordsHolder.size()` in a variable instead of computing it at each step of your for loop.

Comment: The biggest problem is you're iterating through the map rather than using `contains()`, but you should also use `StringBuilder` instead of `StringBuffer` - the former doesn't contain any unnecessary synchronisation when just using it on one thread, so is marginally faster.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle: The `size()` method of `ArrayList` takes constant time. That's not the bottleneck.

Comment: Two things, can you change unmatchingWordsHolder to a Set and what is the key value in iterInWordMap? The key in this example is to try not do the scaning of the whole collection, for that you need to use HashSets. Look at the differentce between HashSets and Lists. If you can use HashSets this will take milliseconds

Comment: @Edd: I used `profiler` in netbeans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does using [`Collection.contains()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) help at all? That would be much more readable, if nothing else, to my mind. It depends on the relative sizes of the `List` and the `Map` though, as the easiest way to do it would be something like this, although since you're iterating over the `Map` and doing the lookup on the `List`, if the `Map` is far larger than the `List` this isn't going to be ideal:

```
private StringBuffer populateStringWithUnmatchingWords(ArrayList<String>unmatchingWordsHolder) {
    StringBuffer unMatchingWordsStr = new StringBuffer();

    for (Entry<String, String> entry : wordMap.entrySet()) {
        if(unmatchingWordsHolder.contains(entry.getValue())) {
            //out.println(matchingWords.get(m)+" : "+true);
            unMatchingWordsStr.append(entry.getKey());
            unMatchingWordsStr.append(",");      
        }
    }
    return unMatchingWordsStr;
}
```

As noted elsewhere, if you don't need thread safety, [`StringBuilder` is generally preferred to `StringBuffer`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6775016/68556), but I didn't want to mess with your method signatures.

Comment: Why not check the other way around? I mean, use: `wordMap.contains(word)` where `word` is a word from the iterable `unmatchingWordsHolder` list. That would be much faster.

Comment: Hi, the code has errors. IDE says `for-each not applicable to expression type
  required: array or java.lang.Iterable
  found:    HashMap`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Problem here is that I need to pass the "value" to get the "key" in this map. Because what I need is located in "Key" not in "value".

Comment: @AmanAgnihotri I did originally look at doing it that way round, but then the issue is looking up the key from a value is O(n), so without using a bi-directional map of some sort I figured this way was probably easier.

Comment: @GloryOfSuccess Fixed now - Should have read `for (Entry<String, String> entry : wordMap.entrySet()) {`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I used another way to achieve this, but yes, same technique, using `contains()`

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating through every element in the `Map`. A better way to do this is to use a `HashMap` and use `contains()` to determine if it exists in the `HashMap`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Problem here is that I need to pass the "value" to get the "key" in this map. Because what I need is located in "Key" not in "value".

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got your problem statement correctly, but if you want to return a comma separated string of all the words that are found in another set of words then here's how you would do in Java 8:

```
private String populateContainedWords(List<String> words, Set<String> wordSet)
{
  StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(", ");

  words.stream().filter(wordSet::contains).forEach(joiner::add);

  return joiner.toString();
}
```

And if you only want to have distinct words in this comma separated string, then use the following approach:

```
private String populateDistinctlyContainedWords(List<String> words, Set<String> wordSet)
{
  StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(", ");

  words.stream().distinct().filter(wordSet::contains).forEach(joiner::add);

  return joiner.toString();
}
```

And if you want a comma separated string of words from the `words` list that are NOT contained in the `wordSet` then here's how that's done:

```
private String populateDisjointWords(List<String> words, Set<String> wordSet)
{
  StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(", ");

  words.stream().filter(n -> !wordSet.contains(n)).forEach(joiner::add);

  return joiner.toString();
}
```